# how to set categorical outputfield in pmml

Tags: pmml

I can set a derivedField like that

```
 <DerivedField name="grouped_pressurex" dataType="string" optype="categorical">
           <MapValues outputColumn="group">
              <FieldColumnPair column="C1" field="TD_SALE_FLG_00M_5" />
              <InlineTable>
                 <row>
                    <C1>low</C1>
                    <group>123</group>
                 </row>
                 <row>
                    <C1>normal</C1>
                    <group>1234</group>
                 </row>
                 <row>
                    <C1>high</C1>
                    <group>12345</group>
                 </row>
              </InlineTable>
           </MapValues>
        </DerivedField>
```

But actually I need that show this field as an output. So I added that code (which in mapvalues tag) in outputField. But it didnt work. How can I do that?

```
<OutputField name="QQQ" optype="categorical" dataType="string" feature="transformedValue">
        <MapValues outputColumn="group">
              <FieldColumnPair column="C1" field="TD_SALE_FLG_00M_5" />
              <InlineTable>
                 <row>
                    <C1>low</C1>
                    <group>123</group>
                 </row>
                 <row>
                    <C1>normal</C1>
                    <group>1234</group>
                 </row>
                 <row>
                    <C1>high</C1>
                    <group>12345</group>
                 </row>
              </InlineTable>
           </MapValues>
        </OutputField>
```

How can I create categorical output field from a data (example TD_SALE_FLG_00M_5) from data dictionary ?

Comment: `But it didn't work` - what software, what's the error message?

Comment: Software is SAS. It didn't give an error. Just doesnt show that variable as output. Just initialized QQQ but not configured by the parameters in mapvalues tag. @user1808924

Comment: My real quesiton is that how can I show a transformatedvalue as outputfield @user1808924

Comment: You are doing everything right. Looks like SAS is just not smart enough to handle a `MapValues` element inside `OutputField` element. You should try different PMML consumer software.